# return a list of data via stored proc to dapper

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, dapper

I am trying to return data using Dapper via stored proc

My DTO Class is similar to below (removed some properties for brevity)

```
public class CarDTO
{
    public int CarID { get; set; }
    public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
    public List<CarOptionDTO> CarOptions { get; set; }
}
```

So basically in the DB I have a CarOption table that has a CarID column - i.e a Car can have many options.

My DAL Layer call at the minute is as below:

```
    private string getCarDataSp = "[dbo].[GetCarData]";

    public IEnumerable<CarDTO> GetCarData(int customerId, int year)
    {
        return Get(db => db.Query<CarDTO>(getCarDataSp , new { CustomerID = customerId, Year = year },
                                commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure));
    }
```

Implementation of my Get function is in my BaseRepository class as:

```
    public T Get<T>(Func<IDbConnection, T> query)
    {
        using (IDbConnection db = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myDB"].ConnectionString))
        {
            return query.Invoke(db);
        }
    }
```

Is it possible using Dapper I can return from my stored proc the CarOptions as well?

My stored proc at the minute is as below:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetCarData]
    @CustomerID int, 
    @Year int
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT * from [dbo].Car c
    JOIN [dbo].Customer cust ON c.CarID = cust.CarID
    WHERE cust.CustID = @CustomerID AND cust.Year = @Year

END
```

the query above may return many rows and the CarID and Manufacturer and the other properties I removed for Brevity. Dapper will map those back to the DTO as expected.

However, it is how to return the list of CarOptions in the stored proc  - is it possible with another query or should it be separated out somehow?  If I have CarID 1 and CarID 2 returned, for example, there may be 6 rows in the CarOption table with CarID 1 and 4 rows in the CarOption table with CarID 2 and ideally, I would like them all to be returned to the CarOptions collection via Dapper if possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes...it is possible. There are a couple of ways of addressing the "one-to-many" scenario with dapper:

## METHOD 1 - Return two queries, combine in DAL

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetCarData]
    @CustomerID int, 
    @Year int
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    --return cars
    SELECT c.*
        from [dbo].Car c
    INNER JOIN [dbo].Customer cust ON c.CarID = cust.CarID
    WHERE cust.CustID = @CustomerID AND cust.Year = @Year

    --return options
    SELECT opt.*
        from [dbo].Car c
    INNER JOIN [dbo].Customer cust ON c.CarID = cust.CarID
    INNER JOIN dbo.CarOptions opt ON op.CarID = c.CarID
    WHERE cust.CustID = @CustomerID AND cust.Year = @Year

END
```

**DAL**

```
var multi = db.QueryMultiple(getCarDataSp , new { CustomerID = customerId, Year = year },
                                commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure));

var cars = multi.Read<CarDTO>();
var options = multi.Read<CarOptionDTO>();

//wire the options to the cars
foreach(var car in cars){
    var carOptions = options.Where(w=>w.Car.CarID == car.CarID);        //I would override Equals in general so you can write w.Car.Equals(car)...do this on a common DataModel class
    car.Options = carOptions.ToList();
}
```

## METHOD 2 - Return one query, split in DAL

**Proc**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetCarData]
    @CustomerID int, 
    @Year int
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;


    SELECT c.*,  opt.*
     from [dbo].Car c
    INNER JOIN [dbo].Customer cust ON c.CarID = cust.CarID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.CarOptions opt ON op.CarID = c.CarID
    WHERE cust.CustID = @CustomerID AND cust.Year = @Year

END
```

**DAL**

```
var tuples = db.Query<CarDTO, CarOptionDTO,Tuple<CarDTO,CarOptionDTO>>(getCarDataSp , new { CustomerID = customerId, Year = year },
(car,opt)=> Tuple.Create(car,opt),                       commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);

//group tuples by car
var cars = tuple.GroupBy(gb=>gb.Item1.CarID)                    //again, overriding equals makes it so you can just to GroupBy(gb=>gb.Item1)
            .Select(s=>{
            var car = s.First().Item1;
            var carOptions = s.Select(t=>t.Item2).ToList()

            return car;
            });
```

## Enhancements

**Using a temp table in the query**

This puts all filtering by parameters into a single query.  Subsequent queries are drop-dead simple selects by ID.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetCarData]
    @CustomerID int, 
    @Year int
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    declare @t table(CarID int);

    --filter cars (only deal with parameters here)
    INSERT INTO @t(CarID)
    SELECT c.CarID
    FROM dbo.Car c
        INNER JOIN [dbo].Customer cust ON c.CarID = cust.CarID
    WHERE cust.CustID = @CustomerID AND cust.Year = @Year

    --return cars
    SELECT c.*
    FROM [dbo].Car c
        INNER JOIN @t t ON t.CarID = c.CarID

    --return options
    SELECT opt.*
    FROM dbo.CarOptions opt
        INNER JOIN @t t ON t.CarID = opt.CarID

END
```

**Applying a BaseDTO to help with equality**

Once you have the BaseDTO, and wire up your ID you can simply say things such as:cars.Where(w=>w.Equals(car)), dictionary[car] (if it's in there), if(car.Equals(otherCar)), or results.GroupBy(gb=>gb.Car)...

```
public class BaseDTO
{
    internal int ID { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// If the obj is the same type with the same id we'll consider it equal.
    /// </summary>
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if(obj == null || this.GetType() != obj.GetType())
        {
            return false;
        }

        return this.GetType().GetHashCode() == obj.GetType().GetHashCode() &&
                this.ID == (BaseDTO)obj.ID;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// If you override equals, you should override gethashcode.  
    /// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263400/what-is-the-best-algorithm-for-an-overridden-system-object-gethashcode#263416
    /// </summary>
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            int hash = 17;

            hash = hash * 23 + this.GetType().GetHashCode();
            hash = hash * 23 + this.ID;

            return hash;
        }
    }
}

public class CarDTO : BaseDTO
{
    public int CarID
    {
        get { return this.ID; }
        set { this.ID = value; }
    }
    public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
    public List<CarOptionDTO> CarOptions { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Great I'll give this a go.  From first glance I like option 2...keeping as much logic as possible in the code and keeping the stored proc 'cleaner'

Comment: The downside to option 2 is that the query size will be fatter...if a car has 50 options, that column data is repeated 50 times (once for each option).  Not a huge concern, but there anyhow.

Comment: Good point.  It could have up to 70 options...unlikely to have more than 10 but the possibility is that it could have up to 70.  Is there any drawback you could see with option 1 apart from have a bit too.much logic in the SP.  I guess having logic in SP has the advantage of being straightforward to deploy if a fix was required

Comment: I think of what you are doing as query logic as opposed to business logic. Query logic(filtering, retrieving) is perfectly acceptable in a sproc. By the way, does it have to be a sproc?  It is soooo much easier to maintain if you pass in the sql directly (use resource files to help manage your sql files too). We converted hundreds of procs and are perfectly happy.

Comment: Yeah unfortunately has to be done with stored procs (which isn't my preference)

Comment: Ok...another tip for the first method is to simply make one query into a temp table that stores your carID and accounts for your filtering (WHERE clause) in one place.  Then, make two extremely clean selects joining the carIDs you just put in a temp.  Basically: 1.) insert into @t select CarID where @cust=xxx...2.) select * from Cars c inner join @t t ON t.CarID = c.CarID 3.) select * from CarOptions co inner join @t t ON t.CarID = co.CarID.

Comment: Cool.  Would you be able to edit the answer to reflect that.  Also could you expand on the over ride you mentioned in the comment in your DAL codd in method 1.  I'll not get chance to Test this until Monday.  Will mark as accepted then.  Thanks for your help btw

Comment: I added an 'enhancements' area at the bottom of my answer that elaborate on those things you mention. So you can just say var carOptions = options.Where(w=>w.Car.Equals(car));

Comment: Hi Blackjacket - I did have a follow up question which I posted - just related to how to wrap your new code in my Generic BaseRepository http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43192696/generic-querymultiple-with-dapper

Comment: Ok...will take a look.

Comment: Cool...as I mentioned though although I would like it possibly in the Base Repository I'm happy that this method is standalone...the old KISS principle is sometimes the best :)