# Generic QueryMultiple with Dapper

Tags: c#, .net, generics, dapper

I have a base repository with a Generic Get method to return Data using Dapper like

```
  public T Get<T>(Func<IDbConnection, T> query)
    {
        using (IDbConnection db = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myDB"].ConnectionString))
        {
            return query.Invoke(db);
        }
    }
```

However I now have the need to return multiple Data.  The DAL query is as below:

```
var multi = db.QueryMultiple(getCarDataSp , new { CustomerID = customerId, Year = year },
                                commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure));

var cars = multi.Read<CarDTO>();
var options = multi.Read<CarOptionDTO>();

//wire the options to the cars
foreach(var car in cars){
    var carOptions = options.Where(w=>w.Car.CarID == car.CarID);        //I would override Equals in general so you can write w.Car.Equals(car)...do this on a common DataModel class
    car.Options = carOptions.ToList();
}
```

Would it be possible to have a Generic GetMultiple in my BaseRepository or would it be a matter of wrapping the get multi in my Get method and then cars and options in there own separate Get calls?

Comment: As your use cases get more complex, solutions become less generally usable. I don't recommend putting something like this in a BaseRepository class. If you are going to, you need several use cases in order to build it correctly.

Comment: Yeah was think similar.  At the minute i have left the implementation for that method seperate and not it the Base Repository and think it fits my needs.  Cheers

Comment: What value does this code add? Just the choice of connection string. And it reduces the whole Dapper surface to a Query call. It's clever n all, but I  don't think it's a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this which will return a tuple containing IEnumerables of each type you are after.

**In Base Repository**

(It's basically a bunch of overloads...you can add more overloads if you have more types).

```
public Tuple<IEnumerable<T1>, IEnumerable<T2>> GetMultiple<T1, T2>(string sql, object parameters,
                                        Func<GridReader, IEnumerable<T1>> func1,
                                        Func<GridReader, IEnumerable<T2>> func2)
        {
            var objs = getMultiple(sql, parameters, func1, func2);
            return Tuple.Create(objs[0] as IEnumerable<T1>, objs[1] as IEnumerable<T2>);
        }

        public Tuple<IEnumerable<T1>, IEnumerable<T2>, IEnumerable<T3>> GetMultiple<T1, T2, T3>(string sql, object parameters,
                                        Func<GridReader, IEnumerable<T1>> func1,
                                        Func<GridReader, IEnumerable<T2>> func2,
                                        Func<GridReader, IEnumerable<T3>> func3)
        {
            var objs = getMultiple(sql, parameters, func1, func2, func3);
            return Tuple.Create(objs[0] as IEnumerable<T1>, objs[1] as IEnumerable<T2>, objs[2] as IEnumerable<T3>);
        }

        private List<object> getMultiple(string sql, object parameters,params Func<GridReader,object>[] readerFuncs )
        {
            var returnResults = new List<object>();
            using (IDbConnection db = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myDB"].ConnectionString))
            {
                var gridReader = db.QueryMultiple(sql, parameters);

                foreach(var readerFunc in readerFuncs)
                {
                    var obj = readerFunc(gridReader);
                    returnResults.Add(obj);
                }
            }

            return returnResults;
        }
```

**In Derived Repository**

(pretty clean and more importantly, typed!)

```
public class Foo { }

        public class Bar { }

        public void sample()
        {
            var sql = "select * from Foo; select * from Bar";
            var foosAndBars = this.GetMultiple(sql, new { param = "baz" }, gr => gr.Read<Foo>(), gr => gr.Read<Bar>());
            var foos = foosAndBars.Item1;
            var bars = foosAndBars.Item2;
        }
```

Comment: I'll give that a go.  I actually had thought usimg Tuple was way to go but got stuck with how to return it correctly.  What would you recommend naming two Generic types?  Ive seen T and U used before in books pr T and TU.  Guess T1 and T2 is fine either just wondering is there a standard convention

Comment: I think The dapper folks use T1,T2... you could overload that up to 8 with generics, with the tuple being the limitation.

Comment: The private method `getMultiple` doesn't really limit you as to the number of results.  All the overloads just type it out for you...but the private method is taking an array of reader funcs, and returning an array of IEnumerables...so it just becomes a casting game.