# Failed to read after called query multiple in dapper

Tags: c#, generics, dapper

I have the following method in the `Helper` class which I am using it with Dapper:

**Helper.cs:**

```
public SqlMapper.GridReader MQueries(string spName, object dynamicParams)
{
  using (IDbConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyConnection"]))
  {
    conn.Open();

    return conn.QueryMultiple(spName, dynamicParams, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
  }
}
```

And I call the above method from another class called `DataAccess`:

**DataAccess.cs:**

```
public Member GetMemberDetails(Member member)
{
  var multi = Helper.MQueries("GetMemberDetails", member);
  var member = multi.Read<Member>().Single();
  var memberStatus = multi.Read<MemberStatus>().Single();
  var memberContact = multi.Read<MemberContact>().ToList();
  var memberFinancial = multi.Read<MemberFinancial>().ToList();

  member.MemberStatus = memberStatus;
  member.MemberContact = memberContact;
  member.MemberFinancial = memberFinancial;

  return member;
}
```

However, the `multi variable` have the data, but once I want to separate it and map into another variable, I got the exception called `cannot read while the reader is closed`.

I know that is because I am used the `using statement`, so after the `multi variable`, the connection get closed automatically, therefore I cant read anything..

How can I solve this?

Your answer much appreciated

Thanks

Comment: You should simply return the dataset instead the reader from the helper method. I don't know exactly which api returns the dataset but I guess you can find this out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The connection is getting closed before you attempt to read it. That won't work.

I would suggest to try like this:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyConnection"]))
using (var result = connection.QueryMultiple("GetMemberDetails", commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure))
{
    //... Consume
}
```

Comment: Hi, if I do like the one that you mentioned in the `Helper` class, how can I get the `Read` as well? Wouldn't it be when I am trying to attempt the `Read`, I will hit the same error again? Thanks

Comment: I have mentioned the code to be used in DataAccess class

Comment: Got it. Thanks, let me check if there is another way to accomplish this, instead of the connection and the query in the dataaccess class

Comment: Can you try to return DataSet or IEnumerable instead of SqlMapper.GridReader?

Comment: I have discover a solution which from someone else answer.. even though it is not a best solution yet for me (or so I think), i will use it for now. Link to another question's answer: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43192696/generic-querymultiple-with-dapper). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create a delegate `Func<SqlMapper.GridReader, Task<T>>` parameter in  `Helper.MQueries()` and put all the `.read()` logic in that `func<>`.