# Dapper multilevel nesting

Tags: c#, dapper

I am trying to use Dapper in my project to speed up data loading (currently using EF6)

Here is my SQL

```
String SQL = @"select vwArtikli_Grid_V2.ArtikalID
    ,vwArtikli_Grid_V2.ArtikalNaziv
    ,Artikli_TagLista.ArtikalTagListaID
    ,Artikli_TagLista.ArtikalTagID
    ,Artikli_Stanje.ArtikalStanjeID
    ,Artikli_Stanje.ObjekatID
    ,Artikli_Stanje.Stanje
    ,Artikli_Tagovi.GrupaID
    ,Artikli_Tagovi.ArtikalTagGrupaID
    ,Artikli_Tagovi.ArtikalTagNaziv
    ,Artikli_Tagovi.ArtikalTagPrint
    ,Artikli_Tagovi.ArtikalTagSlika
    ,Artikli_Tagovi.ArtikalTagID
    ,vwArtikli_Grid_V2.ArtikalID
from Artikli_Tagovi
inner join Artikli_TagLista on Artikli_Tagovi.ArtikalTagID = Artikli_TagLista.ArtikalTagID
right outer join vwArtikli_Grid_V2 on Artikli_TagLista.ArtikalID = vwArtikli_Grid_V2.ArtikalID
left outer join Artikli_Stanje on vwArtikli_Grid_V2.ArtikalID = Artikli_Stanje.ArtikalID;
```

I am using my Entity Framework Entities as POCOs and they are

VwArtikliGridV2, Artikli_TagLista, Artikli_Tagovi, Artikli_Stanje

VwArtikliGridV2 has two properties

```
public virtual ICollection<Artikli_TagLista> Artikli_TagLista { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Artikli_Stanje> Artikli_Stanje { get; set; }
```

and Artikli_TagLista has

```
public virtual Artikli_Tagovi Artikli_Tagovi { get; set; }
```

What is the easiest way to execute the query and map my data to the POCOs or Entities ?

I tried

Dapper.Mapper

```
var Artikli = cn.Query<VwArtikliGridV2, Artikli_TagLista, Artikli_Stanje, Artikli_Tagovi> (SQL);
```

but it didnot work

I also tried Slapper.AutoMapper

```
List<dynamic> ArtikliUM = cn.Query<dynamic>(SQL).ToList();

Slapper.AutoMapper.Configuration.AddIdentifiers(typeof(Artikli_Tagovi), new List<string> { "ArtikalTagID" });
Slapper.AutoMapper.Configuration.AddIdentifiers(typeof(Artikli_TagLista), new List<string> { "ArtikalTagListaID" });
Slapper.AutoMapper.Configuration.AddIdentifiers(typeof(Artikli_Stanje), new List<string> { "ArtikalStanjeID" });


Artikli = (Slapper.AutoMapper.MapDynamic<VwArtikliGridV2>(ArtikliUM) as IEnumerable<VwArtikliGridV2>).ToList();
```

But it also did not work.

I can map VwArtikliGridV2 but i cant map any of the nested objects. They are always null.

What can I try ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dapper maps things flat.  At first this feels like a big pain because EF nests things so easily.  But once you get over the initial pain you realize how simple, predictable, and performance-oriented it is.  Maybe an extra 15 min. of query-crafting for untouchable performance.

I answered a similar question here [return a list of data via stored proc to dapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43142432/return-a-list-of-data-via-stored-proc-to-dapper/43147969#43147969).

You should be able to return multiple datasets (one for the parent item, one for the underlying tags, etc.) and combine them in your app tier.

Answer (score 0):

As BlackjacketMack said in his answer, I think multiple data sets are the way to go.

You might want to look in the Dapper documentation at the features **Multi Mapping** to split single rows into multiple objects, and **QueryMultiple** to read multiple result sets from a single query.

Obviously, it would mean modifying your query to return multiple result sets, but could achieve what you are looking for.

Examples can be found here: https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/blob/master/Dapper.Tests/MultiMapTests.cs

https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/blob/master/Dapper.Tests/QueryMultipleTests.cs

In particular, you might want to take a look at method `public void TestMultiMapThreeTypesWithGridReader()` in MultiMapTests.cs. I found that very useful to help me understand a similar problem of parent with child collections, where the child contains different object types returned in a single row.